dayjs: Wrong hours in diff
I have the following code fragment in node.js written in Typescript to calculate the Difference between two Dates:
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import duration from 'dayjs/plugin/duration'
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc'
...
dayjs.extend(duration)
dayjs.extend(utc)
...
const date1 = dayjs().utc() // 2024-10-31T06:58:42Z
const date2 = dayjs('2025-03-13 00:00:00').utc()
const diff = dayjs.duration(date2.diff(date1))

This returns the wrong number of hours:
diff l {
  '$d': {
    years: 0,
    months: 4,
    days: 11,
    hours: 0, // This is wrong!
    minutes: 1,
    seconds: 17,
    milliseconds: 5
  },
  '$l': 'en',
  '$ms': 11462477005
}

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
dayjs 1.11.12; node.js 23.0.0
Update
This seems to be a problem with all dayjs versions > 1.11.9. I have created an Issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/2762

It clearly parses $ms to $d wrong. Consider opening an issue
